# Control ItemsSource binding does not update on ClickOnce Web Published WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, clickonce

I have a WPF application with an XAML Window containing a few Buttons and a DataGrid. When buttons are pressed, some logic is performed in the background which builds a list of some type and finally assigns the list to a (MVVM) model property "DataSource" to which an ItemsSource of the DataGrid is bound to like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Grid.Row ="10" ...
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSource, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
```

When the content of DataSource is changed, DataGrid is aware of that and shows the new data. So far all good, application works as intended and with no problems. I can copy the bin output of build and sucessfully run it just about everywhere.

Then comes ClickOnce publish. **If published so that it installs from, and is installed from an Unc network share, e.g. \SomeServer\SomePath\InstallFromDir\, everything still works fine.**

**But if published so that it installs from, and is installed from an online url, e.g. http://companydomain.com/InstallFromDir/, DataGrid simply does not update.**

**Nothing else is changed but the method of app and updates availability from unc to web.**

What I gathered from debugging trace points still applies. The list in the background is built anew. It is assigned to the DataSource property (if I verify the contained data, it does contain the new data). But if I access the DataGrids ItemsSource it still contains the OLD, initial data.

I have tried re-assigning the DataSource to ItemsSource -- doesn't help. I have tried re-binding the data when it changes programatically, as in:

```
var sourceBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("DataSource"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true,
    NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(((MainWindow)_window).DataGrid,
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, sourceBinding);
```

and even changing the xaml so that it is ONLY bound in code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Grid.Row ="10" ... >
```

and it still works the same as described above: works as direct copy or unc install, but doesn't work as web install.

I am totally lost as to either finding the cause or finding the workarounds. Anyone encountered this before? Any ideas? Many thanks!

**Update:** I have initially thought this was a DataGrid issue, but I have since also tried replacing DataGrid with ListView, and it doesn't work either.